Reduced relative clause or participle clause?
According to my CAE Student's Book, the participle clause doesn't replace a relative clause in the following sentence:

Business Week ran a story called My Virtue Life, explaining breathlessly that "big advertisers are taking notice".

I wonder why this sentence can't be considered as a reduced relative clause. In my view, all the conditions have been met.
Indeed, this sentence is another way to say that:

Business Week ran a story called My Virtue Life which explains breathlessly that "big advertisers are taking notice".

The relative clause here uses the present tense, modifies the subject/object of the verb in the main clause, as well as it is a defining relative clause. So, as I see it, we can transform it into the above sentence with participle clause "-ing".
Could you tell me please where I'm mistaken?

Note the difference between

[1a] Business Week ran a story called My Virtue Life, explaining breathlessly that "big advertisers are taking notice".

and

[2a] Business Week ran a story called My Virtue Life explaining breathlessly that "big advertisers are taking notice".

The comma in the first version conventionally forces attachment of the participial clause 'explaining breathlessly that "big advertisers are taking notice" ' to 'Business Week'. Whether or not this was the intended sense, the correct paraphrase is

[1b] Business Week ran a story called My Virtue Life; in it they explained breathlessly that "big advertisers are taking notice".                             ['they' the writers/editors/contributors/...]

The commaless version is correctly paraphrased by

Business Week ran a story called My Virtue Life which explains breathlessly that "big advertisers are taking notice".

.......................
The whole issue of reduced relative clauses and whiz-deletion is rejected by some very respected grammarians (though it should be acceptable to all if the concept is regarded as an artifice, a trick for reliably arriving at condensed paraphrases, rather than describing an actual grammatical transformation). Though Nordquist gives a 'how to' list, which seems very much like an espousal of the transformation interpretation.

Thank you so much @Edwin Ashworth for your detailed reply! Could you tell me please whether you are agree with my analysis that the initial sentence could be considered as a reduced relative clause?

With the comma, I'd say that even those who believe in 'reduced relative clauses' would not allow this to be classed as one; the associated 'Business Week ran a story called My Virtue Life which explains breathlessly that "big advertisers are taking notice" ' has 'which explains ...' modifying 'a story' whereas the original has 'explaining ...' modifying 'Business Week'. And without the comma, the sentence is clunky and really needs rephrasing (as in say [1b] above).

Oh, now I see! Thank you so much @Edwin Ashworth!

I should have said 'addressing 'Business Week' in line 4 of the comment above: modification in the strict sense isn't applied to adjuncts, which essentially add on an abbreviated second sentence (as shown in the paraphrase [1b]).

Nice, +1. However ... I would agee that it's ok when the concept is regarded as a trick, a heurisitc for reliably arrriving at a condensed para phrase, were it not for the fact that it's not at all reliable (which is the main reason that it's rejected!!!). Consider: That's the doctor who is a student or That's the man who is dead.

Two sentences with the same subject can be combined by reducing one of them to a participle clause (warning: grammar terms vary). The subject here is Business Week:

Business Week ran a story called My Virtue Life.
+Business Week explained breathlessly that “big advertisers are taking notice.”
=
Business Week ran a story called My Virtue Life, explaining breathlessly that “big advertisers are taking notice.”

If you remove the comma, you could instead interpret it as you have, but that changes the meaning—now the article rather than the magazine is breathlessly explaining.
Compare these:

I wrote a story. I explained my fascination with cats. I wrote
a story, explaining my fascination with cats. ? I wrote a
story, which explains my fascination with cats. (no place for a relative pronoun here)
I wrote a story. The story explains my fascination with cats.
I wrote a story that explains my fascination with cats. I
wrote a story explaining my fascination with cats.

